# "Big ear" of polygons: proper nomenclature

Tags: geometry, terminology, polygons, convention

I've developed a polygon triangulation algorithm which uses a process similar to the "Graham Scan" to remove convex "portions" of a concave polygon.
I couldn't find the proper nomenclature for those "portions", and I'd like to name the algorithm after it.

I'm not a mathematician, so I can't provide a formal definition, but it extends the concept of an "Ear" - a triangle formed by a convex vertex and it's neighbours, which contains no other vertex inside it - to a consecutive convex subset of points of the polygon.

The algorithm for finding a "big ear" is:

- Start from a reflex vertex $v(p)$, so that $v(p+1)$ is not reflex
- Iterate forward
- For each vertex $v(p+n), n \ge 1$, check if the angle $[v(p+n+1),v(p),v(p+1)]$ is smaller than $180^\circ$

  - If yes, continue
  - If no, the "big ear" ends on $v(p+n)$
- Check if there's a vertex inside the "big ear" ending on $v(p+n+1)$

  - If yes, the "big ear" ends on $v(p+n)$
  - If no, continue

[image: ear or not an ear]

EDIT:

I forgot to list two supplementary rules:

- If $v(p+1)$ is reflex, do $p = p+1$ and start over
- If $n>1$, before any further check, if $v(p+n)$ is reflex close a "big ear" on $v(p+n)$

[image: supplementary rules]

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard terminology for this, but "maximal convex subpolygon" sounds like a reaosnable name to me.

Comment: I am not sure how complicated is to calculate angels... A "concave" vertex will be defined by the sign of the line equation with adjacent one vertex when you insert the values of the other adjacent vertex. If the signs are different (you may use (0,0) as reference).